# SQL query to find team name which played most

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a query to display the names of the teams which has played maximum number of games. In case of multiple records, display the records sorted in ascending order based on team name.

**this is my query i dont know how to display max team name using game count**

```
select t.name,count(*) as game_count 
   from game g,team t 
   where (g.team_id_1 = t.id or g.team_id_2 = t.id) 
   group by t.name order by game_count desc;
```

**i have to find team name which has played most**

**I am new to MySQL and not able to figure out the correct/most efficient query for that, please help.**

Game table having columns

ID  GAME_DATE   TEAM_ID_1   TEAM_ID_2

Team table having columns

ID  NAME

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Comment: Please do not post screen shots but code/table structure as well as @jens comment

Comment: On a sidenote: Don't use comma-separated joins. They went out of fashion before MySQL was even invented. Use proper joins: `from game g join team t on t.id in (g.team_id_1, g.team_id_2)`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a little involved for a homework question. Can you use table expressions?

```
with summary as (
    select team_id, count(*) cnt from (
        select team_id_1 team_id from game union all
        select team_id_2 from game
    ) g
    group by team_id
)
select * from t where team_id in (
    select team_id from summary where cnt = (select max(cnt) from summary)
)
order by name;
```

Comment: type With is not supported in MySQL version less than 8 for that how to find max.
this is not home work but i need logic to find max sum belongs to some id for example purpose i had taken this question

Answer (score 0):

Use group by and having with a sub query to match against max number of played

```
select t.name as name, count(*) as gcount
from game g
join team t on t.id = g.team1 or t.id = g.team2 
group by t.name
having count(g.id) = (
    select count(g.id) games
    from game g
    join team t on t.id = g.team1 or t.id = g.team2 
    group by t.name
    order by games desc
    limit 1)
```

Comment: tq but do not use limit for the condition if max count repeated for different team name.

Comment: @LearningCenter What do you mean? If two teams with the most games  both have played 5 games then how does it matter which team the limit refers to in the sub query, it’s the count (5) that is the returned and only interesting result.

Comment: if counts has (5) for both team means have to print both teams

Comment: @LearningCenter yes and my query does that.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.name from team t,game g where  t.id = g.team_id_1 or t.id = g.team_id_2  
  group by t.id having count(*) = (
  select max(cnt) from (select t.name,coalesce(count(*),0) cnt 
  from game g,team t 
  where  t.id = g.team_id_1 or t.id = g.team_id_2  group by t.id)a) 
  order by t.name;
```

Solved thanks for the ideas

Comment: `count()` never returns null.